# "maximum number of concurrent connections exceeded" get exception in isapi application in Delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

If i send more than 32 request to server at a time then it returns 500 errorcode in apache log. the error message is

> maximum number of concurrent connections exceeded

Comment: Before posting here please read the articles here: [help]

Comment: It is impossible to understand your question.  Apache is simply saying that you are opening more than the maximum number of concurrent connections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`32` is the default value for [`TWebRequestHandler.MaxConnections`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Web.WebReq.TWebRequestHandler.MaxConnections) property. If the number of active connections exceeds this value the Web Broker framework will raise an `EWebBrokerException` with the message:

> "Maximum number of concurrent connections exceeded.  Please try again
>   later"

You can set it to a higher value or zero to indicate no limit.

Since you mention Apache in your case the right place to do this is your Apache DLL's main block, for example:

```
begin
  CoInitFlags := COINIT_MULTITHREADED;
  Web.ApacheApp.InitApplication(@GModuleData);
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.WebModuleClass := WebModuleClass;
  Application.MaxConnections := 200;
  Application.Run;
end.
```